# Can anyone identify this Knowles Donau microspeaker connector?

Tags: components, speakers

Can anyone identify this type of connector? I need to purchase a bunch of these connectors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a two-pin JST connector, commonly found on hobby batteries.

Search Sparkfun.com for "JST" to see a variety of compatible connectors.

Or look for "mating products" at Digi-Key page for part 455-1165-ND.

e.g, 455-1734-1-ND

[image]

Comment: Great! I think it is a JST 1mm pitch now. I'm going to order one and try it

Comment: Hmm the sparkfun only goes down to 2mm. I could only find manufacturing sites selling plain connectors that still required wiring and soldering. Is there anywhere to get the sparkfun style "2mm pitch JST male to wires" in 1mm?